# Help text not displaying in vf page when i use output panel

Tags: visualforce, outputpanel, helptext

I'm trying to display helptext of a custom field using below code but it is not displaying because of apex:outputpanel  need hepl

```
    <page>
    <apex:form>
     <apex:pageblock>
       <apex:pageblocksection>
         <apex:outputpanel id="abcid">
            <apex:pageblocksectionitem helptext="{!$Objecttype.abcobj.fields.abcfeld.inlinehelptext}">
            </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
         <apex:outputpanel>
         </apex:pageblocksection>
    </apex:pageblock> 
  </apex:form>
</page>
```

i want output panel before apex:pageblocksectionitem any help

Comment: <page>
    <apex:form>
     <apex:pageblock>
       <apex:pageblocksection>
         <apex:outputpanel id="abcid">
            <apex:pageblocksectionitem helptext="{!$Objecttype.abcobj.fields.abcfeld.inlinehelptext}">
          ......  </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
         </apex:outputpanel>
          </apex:pageblocksection>
    </apex:pageblock> 
  </apex:form>
</page>

Answer (score 0):

can you try the following code to display help text with outputpanel.

```
<apex:form >
     <apex:pageblock >
     <apex:outputpanel id="abcid">
       <apex:pageblocksection >           
            <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.Multiselect__c}"/>           
         </apex:pageblocksection>
         </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageblock> 
  </apex:form>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply shravan, but I can't try this way bcz there are more than one apex:pageblocksectionitem  and i'm using outputpanel to rereneder two of them in apex:pageblocksection .